# Is there an addon that can subdivide a mesh in edit-mode like the subdivision surface modifier does?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, add-on, edit-mode

I have already tried tweaking the default *Smooth* slider for the modifier and it still does not seem to help the issue.

Comment: select all, right click > Subdivide?

Comment: Cant u just add another subdiv modifier normally and apply it? Its like 2 clicks more

Comment: @moonboots no,that's exactly what I say very different from using different,though I can just add a modifier and apply it,but I want find a way that can make this directly in edit mode,which is much more convenient

Comment: You can do it in edit mode, after subdividing in edit mode go to the foldout in the lower left of the screen or press F9 and sett smoothness to 1. however it's not exactly the same thing as the modifier https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccpL7.png

Answer (score -1):

Select the edges and faces you want to subdivide, then <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> key or <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>D</kbd> key to select the *subdivide* option.

What you're asking is if you can do Catmull Clark surface subdivision and have it applied instantly. No, you can't. You have to select the object, add the  subdivision surface modifier then apply it. You can apply modifiers by pressing <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> on a highlighted modifier or using the dropdown menu below:

[image]

Using the Catmull Clark subdivision surface modifier then applying it and the Subdivide function in *Edit mode* are two very different things that are used in different situations for different purposes.

Comment: Subdividing in edit mode  is for **parts** of your mesh unlike the subdiv modifier that applies to **the whole** mesh

Comment: Yeah! This person is very new to Blender. A little too new, they should be using a tutorial.